# selecting available rooms from the database using start and end time

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

```
bookings(id, title, start_time, end_time, date, room_id) 

rooms(id, name, status )
```

A user is supposed to enter the start time,  end time and the date in the form and then compared them with the end_time and start of the already existing events in the database in then return a list of available rooms   to  the user so that he can book that room. how can I do this in mysql and php.Thank you.

Comment: I'd start with a tutorial on room bookings, PHP, and MySQL

Comment: what are you using in PHP to access the database? PDO?

Comment: You just connect that two tables using a key value

Comment: Am using Mysqli to access the database

Comment: I would like to have an sql statement that selects all free rooms from the database after the user has entered the start and end time of their events